# Нужен ли здесь дефис при описании оттенков цвета?

Tags: прилагательные, дефис, раздельно-дефис, сложные-прилагательные

Нужен ли здесь дефис? "Насыщенно зелёный", "ярко красный", "густо фиолетовый". Встречала варианты написания с дефисом и без. Так как всё-таки правильно? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Fuchoin Kazuki! Дефис не знак пунктуации. Это орфографический вопрос.

Answer (score 8):

Ярко-красный, густо-фиолетовый пишутся через дефис, так как обозначают оттенки цвета.  Насыщенно-зеленый, думаю, тоже. Насыщенно- то же, что и густо-... Хотя если насыщенно в смысле "очень", то, возможно и раздельно. Но очень похоже на разговорный вариант... Может, лучше сказать "насыщенный зеленый"?

Comment: Да, можно сказать "насыщенный зеленый", но мне интересен именно этот вариант - "насыщенно зеленый". Хочется разобраться именно с ним. Где-то читала, что дефис не нужен: "Это не оттенок цвета."Насыщенно" - это обстоятельство степени". Но в то же время очень часто вижу написание через дефис.

Answer (score 1):

Все эти прилагательные следует писать через дефис (см. правило [здесь](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=49)).

> 11. Пишутся через дефис сложные прилагательные, обозначающие оттенки цветов: *бледно-голубой*, *блёкло-розовый*, *бутылочно-зелёный* <...>

"Насыщенно" тоже подпадает под это правило, "Грамота.ру" даже отвечала на схожий вопрос, подтвердив дефисное написание прилагательного "насыщенно-красный" (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=308742)).

В "Нацкорпусе" встречается и раздельное, и дефисное написание.

1. Примеры раздельного написания.

*Мясо у них оранжево-желтое или **насыщенно зелёное**, как шартрез. [Ю. О. Домбровский. Факультет ненужных вещей, часть 1 (1978)]*

*Беленая вселенная перетекала в еще одну, **насыщенно зеленую**, оранжерейную. [С. А. Самсонов. Аномалия Камлаева (2006-2007)]*

*Соцветия осоки черной (Carex nigra) кажутся **насыщенно черными** на фоне голубоватых молодых листьев с металлическим блеском. [Александр Марченко. Метаморфозы водного сада (2001) // «Ландшафтный дизайн», 15.07.2001]*

2. Примеры дефисного написания.

***Насыщенно-синие** и лиловые цвета ― визитная карточка художника. [Д. П. Дроздов. Большая Ордынка. Прогулка по Замоскворечью от Москворецкого моста до Серпуховской площади (2017)]*

*Я помню тёмно-красное вельветовое платье, потому что тёмно-красных вельветовых платьев у меня было целых два ― одно **насыщенно-вишнёвое**, с вышивками гладью на кармашках, другое ― чуть старшее: сдержанно-блёклое и без особых изысков, чем и благородное. [Татьяна Соломатина. Мой одесский язык (2011)]*

*И тогда, выйдя из дома с зеленым интерьером, вы увидите сначала **насыщенно-пурпурные** листья, а уже вслед за этим обратите внимание на **насыщенно-изумрудную** зелень сада. [Александр Сапелин. Царственное убранство: пурпур и золото (2003) // «Ландшафтный дизайн», 15.03.2003]*

**ВЫВОД**

Вероятно, в первом случае авторы считают, что "насыщенно" — обстоятельство меры и степени, а во втором — часть сложного прилагательного. Второй случай базируется на вышеупомянутом правиле, так что к вам будет не придраться, если вы будете ему следовать, то есть напишете: **насыщенно-зелёный**, равно как и **ярко-красный** и **густо-фиолетовый**.